# OpenCV Black and White video empty

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have some code to record a video using `openCV`. It works fine for recording colour video, but I'd like to record black and white.

When I call `cvtColor` to black and white I get an empty video. I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    VideoCapture cap(1); // open the default camera
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, fps);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;


    VideoWriter writer(filename, CV_FOURCC('M','P','4','2'), fps, Size(1280, 720), true);

    int count = 0; 
    for(;;)
    {
        count++;
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        //cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        writer.write(frame);
    }
```

The above code produces a perfectly fine video, but when `cvtColor` is uncommented the file is empty.

Comment: First of all, check that the frame has 3 channels (could have 1 or 4 too). Secondly, change `CV_BGR2GRAY` to `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` in case you have 3 channels. When you've done this, try to debug to check how many rows and cols `frame` has. Let me know.

Comment: I've changed the flag to `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` and printed out the columns and rows of `frame` are 1280 x 720 both before and after the `cvtColor` call, but still the video is empty

Comment: Could you please do a couple of this more ? 1.- change `writer.write(frame);` to `writer << frame;` and 2.- before showing it, just do a `imshow(frame)` just to check that it's the correct frame you're looking for. Tell me if 1 or 2 goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to make b/w video with XVID codec and got empty film too (5kB length), until I made FFMPEG libraries available to program (put them together with program or in PATH-ed directory, Windows OS).

OpenCV checks for FFMPEG presence and uses it if available.

And aside remark - use the second Mat for b/w frame - it will save computer time (with single object every capture causes two reallocations/reinitializations)

```
 cvtColor(frame, bwframe, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```